# How to write a string from a text file into an XML file using batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a text file containing the log of a msi that looks like this

```
=== Logging started: 11/29/2019  15:27:45 ===
Action start 15:27:45: INSTALL.
Action start 15:27:45: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 15:27:45: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 15:27:45: ValidateProductID.
Action ended 15:27:45: ValidateProductID. Return value 1.
Action start 15:27:45: CostInitialize.
Property(N): UpgradeCode = {x}
Property(N): TARGETDIR = E:\
Property(N): INSTALLDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Temp\
Property(N): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(N): PASSWORD = x
Property(N): ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT = 123 
Property(N): Location = "xyz"
=== Logging stopped: 11/29/2019  15:28:45 ===
```

I want to write the value of Location into a an XML file into a tag called location using batch script
I've never used batch script myself, so please any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
@echo off
echo ^<xml^> >script.xml
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%a in ('type [the name of your msi log txt file].txt ^| find "Location"') do (echo ^<location^>%%a^</location^> >>script.xml)
echo ^</xml^> >>script.xml
goto :eof
```

Replace "[the name of your msi log txt file]" with your own. It will create an XML file named script.xml with the data.
If you have more words in the location, see the `tokens` field in the batch file, write a comma and enter 5 (if you have more words go on like this, the number 5 will increase as you go).

Comment: This code does not work if the location string contains a space character, i.e. is for example `Dhaka, Bangladesh` instead of `xyz`. The question is much too broad for being answered at all.

Comment: Thank you that worked, but it seems to be overwriting the other contents of the XML file is there anyway to simply append it instead of overwriting it?

Comment: What?, it does not append? Do you have any other XML files with this name in your current directory.

Comment: ok changing the > operator to  >> operator in the line ```echo ^<xml^> >script.xml``` seems to fix the problem. change it to this ```echo ^<xml^> >>script.xml```